# netCDF4.append problem python , merge NC files

Tags: pandas, netcdf4

I'm trying to merge several netCDF4 from ERA-5 Land into 1 file to read it. But, I have problems with append. Could you help me with?

I have tried but the error is

File src\netCDF4_netCDF4.pyx:2028 in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success

AttributeError: NetCDF: Attribute not found

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# List of year files
year_files = [r'path/Europe_1970.nc', r'path/Europe_1971.nc', r'path/Europe_1972.nc']

# Merge yearly files into one file
merged_file = r'path/merged_file.nc'
nc_merge = nc.Dataset(merged_file, 'w')

for year_file in year_files:
    with nc.Dataset(year_file) as nc_in:
        if not nc_merge.dimensions:
            # Create dimensions in the merged file
            for dim_name, dim in nc_in.dimensions.items():
                nc_merge.createDimension(dim_name, len(dim))

            # Copy variables from the first file to the merged file
            for var_name, var in nc_in.variables.items():
                nc_out_var = nc_merge.createVariable(var_name, var.dtype, var.dimensions)
                nc_out_var[:] = var[:]

        else:
            # Append variables from subsequent files to the merged file
            for var_name, var in nc_in.variables.items():
                nc_out_var = nc_merge.variables[var_name]
                nc_out_var.append(var[:], axis=0)

# Close the merged file
nc_merge.close()

# Read the merged file using netCDF4
data = nc.Dataset(merged_file)
```